# When is Stack Overflow podcast #85 due?

Tags: support, podcast

Some of us are running low on [dopamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine#Dopamine.2C_learning.2C_and_reward-seeking_behavior). When can we expect Stack Overflow podcast 85?

Comment: I wonder if this is now on the 6-8 weeks schedule.

Comment: I can hook you up with something that can take care of your dopamine levels...

Comment: @Ether lol, try some Mucuna pruriens (Velvet Bean). Its readily available from the health food store, what your talking about will just use it up (as opposed to replenish) :)

Answer (score 9):

Jeff is currently on vacation the Land of Mordor - trying to return his iPhone to Mount doom.

Joel doesn't know how to post new entries, because you can't do it with Excel-VBA.

Comment: Sweet and cruel! I like it ;)

Comment: Maybe if he visits across the ditch he might rid himself of his negative attitudes to us Australians (we still haven't forgiven him for this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/)

Comment: I thought it was a two-week vacation, and it's been 4 since the last podcast with Jeff was published.

Comment: Have YOU ever tried to park at Mount Doom ?